# What does ようにと言う mean in 薬を飲んで様子を見るようにと言われました？

Tags: meaning, particle-と

This is the context:

> 今朝はここちゃんを動物病院に連れて行きました。診断結果はスナッフルでした。うさぎにはよくある病気で、薬を飲んで様子を見る**ようにと言われました**。

I know the expression ように言う, but why is there a と in ~ように**と**言われました?

Comment: This is a perfectly ordinary quotative と (and the fact that it's followed by a conjugation of 言う is a dead giveaway), so there should be any number of duplicates already... ?

Answer (score 7):

It's a matter of punctuation.

（先生）「薬を飲んで、様子を見るように！」

と（先生に）言われました。

If you break it down like that, it should make sense. The confusing part (for the latin-based language speakers) is that it is fine to omit the quotes, it is a form of narrative that is frequently used. It's akin to "I've been told to take meds and see how it goes." vs "I have been told, 'Take meds, and see how it goes.'"

Comment: To add, the "と" here is like, 面白いと思います。( I think that's interesting. ) 
せっかく料理したのに、まずいと言われてしまいました。 ( I put in some effort cooking this, but I've been told it just doesn't taste good. )

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not so sure that "ように" can end a sentence, but I notice that it does in "「薬を飲んで、様子を見るように！」". Is that because "してくたさい" has been omitted after "ように"? Just like @N. Hunt said?

Comment: Yes, exactly so. It is also seen in this workplace notice. "The last person out must lock the windows and doors." 最後の人は戸締りを忘れないように

https://peragami.com/?p=9081

Comment: Another one for you: グラフィックボードの取り付け。補助電源を忘れないように "Installing the graphics board: Do not forget to connect the supplemental power supply."

https://shikaolog.com/pc-selfmade-11/

Comment: It should be also noted, that these uses of ending with ように are spoken from position of authority, like the workplace telling employee what to do, doctor telling patients what to do, PC builder's guide telling noobs what not to do. So, overuse it and you might come across arrogant.

Comment: Thank you very much for these detailed explanations! I got it.

Comment: Forgot to mention, there's another class of usage: wish making and praying. 世界が平和でありますように。Let there be peace on earth. 背が伸びますように (kids might say a prayer wishing to be taller) and so on...it could be thought of as telling deities what to do!

Answer (score 5):

After ように you can assume してくたさい has been omitted, thus ようにと is the way one indicates a command indirectly, i.e., 'I was told to [see to/make sure] I watch [his/her/its] condition'. More simply, 'I was told "Watch his/her/its condition"'.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the previous answers, ように can be used to make a request in combination with と, but you don't necessarily have to use the verb 言う. Other verbs that add different nuances work with ように[と] too:

> 彼女に許すようにと**願う**。To **beg** her to forgive [you].
>
> 田中さんにレポートを作るようにと**頼む**。To **request** Tanaka to write a report.
>
> 太郎にテーブルを食卓の用意するようにと**言う**。To **tell** Tarou to set the dinning table.

Also note that と is optional here. You can also say ように願う, ように頼む or ように言う and it means the same.